# How to sum using where or case in a group by?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this result set from a group by expression:

[image]

This is from:

```
SELECT
    list.Id, 
    SUM(answer.score) totalScoreOfList
    --,sum(answer.score) score of student id 5.. something like sum(answer.score) where studentId = 5
    -- or case when studenti.id = 5 then sum(answer.score) else 0 end
FROM
    list
LEFT JOIN student ...
LEFT JOIN answer ...
GROUP BY 
    exercise.id
```

What technique can I use to get the result above?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question title says, you need to use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    list.Id, 
    SUM(answer.score) totalScoreOfList,
    SUM(CASE WHEN studentId = 5 THEN answer.score END) [score of student id 5]
FROM
    list
LEFT JOIN student ...
LEFT JOIN answer ...
GROUP BY 
    list.id;
```

Comment: @MuriloKunze then the part of your code that you didn't post is breaking the query

Answer (score 1):

you can use case when as below:

```
SELECT
    list.Id, 
    SUM(answer.score) totalScoreOfList,
    SUM(case when StudentId = 5 then answer.score else 0 end) as TotalScoreOfStudentWithid5
...
```